# How to remove empty rows in csv using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I got csv dataset like this and i need to remove any empty rows inside of it i already tried following code but still it fails when it reads empty row, and return

`pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 11, saw 8`

```
    def feed_db():
        try:
            employees = pd.read_csv(
                'employee.csv', delimiter=',',  sep='\t', encoding="utf-8", header=None, skipinitialspace=True, skip_blank_lines=True)
            employees.columns = [c.strip().lower().replace(' ', '_')
                                 for c in employees.columns]
            employees.to_sql('employees', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
    
        except Error as exc:
            raise Error('Database initialization failed', exc)
```

sample dataset

```
Employee Id, Full Name, Gender, Date of Birth, Joined Date, Salary (USD), Branch
EN_0001, Aditi Musunur, Male, 1990-03-24, 2011-07-05, 1500, Sri Lanka
EN_0002, Advitiya Sujeet, Male, 1986-07-28, 2010-03-24, 1600, Sri Lanka
EN_0003, Alagesan Poduri, Male, 1982-05-25, 2016-06-24, 1800, Sri Lanka
EN_0004, Amrish Ilyas, Female, 1987-10-24, 2013-12-17, 2000, India
EN_0005, Aprativirya Seshan, Female, 1981-12-16, 2012-03-14, 1750, India
EN_0006, Asvathama Ponnada, Male, 1986-01-09, 2014-06-18, 2300, Pakistan
EN_0007, Avantas Ghosal, Female, 1981-10-05, 2016-08-26, 4200, Pakistan
EN_0008, Avidosa Vaisakhi, Male, 1980-08-09, 2018-03-05, 3100, Bangladesh
EN_0009, Barsati Sandipa, Male, 1988-04-09, 2011-05-03, 2925, Bangladesh
EN_0010, Debasis Sundhararajan, Female, 1990-03-26, 2015-05-18, , 2800, Bangladesh
EN_0011, Debas Sundhar, Female, 1990-03-26, 2015-05-18, 2800, Bangladesh
```

how can i remove those empty rows using pandas ?

Comment: could you post line 11 of the CSV please?

Comment: There is a problem in your CSV, indeed line 11 has 8 fields and not 7 (the 6th is empty), correct your CSV :)

Comment: so, is it possible to remove it, through code ?

Comment: it is not the scope of Pandas. You have to fix your CSV first in other ways.

Comment: :-P if the dataset contains 10000 of records, then how should this be done ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229735/discussion-between-marcop-and-pl-jay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, there is a redundant empty cell in line 11. You can open and fix the `csv`, write it to `StringIO`, then open it with `pd.read_csv`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
s = io.StringIO()

with open('employee.csv') as file:
    for line in file:
        s.write(str(line).replace(", ,", ","))
s.seek(0)

df = pd.read_csv(s)
```

result:

|  | Employee Id | Full Name | Gender | Date of Birth | Joined Date | Salary (USD) | Branch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | EN_0001 | Aditi Musunur | Male | 1990-03-24 | 2011-07-05 | 1500 | Sri Lanka |
| 1 | EN_0002 | Advitiya Sujeet | Male | 1986-07-28 | 2010-03-24 | 1600 | Sri Lanka |
| 2 | EN_0003 | Alagesan Poduri | Male | 1982-05-25 | 2016-06-24 | 1800 | Sri Lanka |
| 3 | EN_0004 | Amrish Ilyas | Female | 1987-10-24 | 2013-12-17 | 2000 | India |
| 4 | EN_0005 | Aprativirya Seshan | Female | 1981-12-16 | 2012-03-14 | 1750 | India |
| 5 | EN_0006 | Asvathama Ponnada | Male | 1986-01-09 | 2014-06-18 | 2300 | Pakistan |
| 6 | EN_0007 | Avantas Ghosal | Female | 1981-10-05 | 2016-08-26 | 4200 | Pakistan |
| 7 | EN_0008 | Avidosa Vaisakhi | Male | 1980-08-09 | 2018-03-05 | 3100 | Bangladesh |
| 8 | EN_0009 | Barsati Sandipa | Male | 1988-04-09 | 2011-05-03 | 2925 | Bangladesh |
| 9 | EN_0010 | Debasis Sundhararajan | Female | 1990-03-26 | 2015-05-18 | 2800 | Bangladesh |
| 10 | EN_0011 | Debas Sundhar | Female | 1990-03-26 | 2015-05-18 | 2800 | Bangladesh |

Answer (score 0):

Your csv file has an extra comma on this line:

```
EN_0010, Debasis Sundhararajan, Female, 1990-03-26, 2015-05-18, , 2800, Bangladesh
```